# why GPU utilization is not high with TensorFlow task

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I write a demo code to test the GPU utilisation. why is it only round 30%, even I increase the nodes number and layer number, and batch_size, it seems the utilisation is not over 50%. Can some one help to figure out the problem, Thanks very much!

'''

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import tensorflow as tf

train_x = np.random.random((4000000,300))

train_y = np.random.randint(2, size=4000000)
train_y = to_categorical(train_y, num_classes=2)


def create_model():
    input_layer = Input(shape=(300,), dtype=float)
    x = layers.Dense(900, activation='relu')(input_layer)
    x = layers.Dense(16000, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(16000, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(16000, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(16000, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(240, activation='relu')(input_layer)
    output_layer = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(input_layer,output_layer)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['acc'])
    return model

model = create_model()
model.fit(train_x,train_y,epochs=500,batch_size=1024, validation_split=0.1)
```

'''

Comment: Reason behind this behavior can be latency for loading data to GPU memory. If so increasing size of net will increase GPU utilization.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add layers to enlarge the model, but the GPU utilisation is still low.

Answer (score 1):

Before start of your code, you can do some configuration on GPU level to work based on your desire.
As mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth) you can `set_memory_growth` as `True` like below.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```